# .NET MAUI input string was not in a correct format

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I'm still learning .NET MAUI, so what I have done wrong might be a simple fix.

I'm trying to create a small control, but I keep getting an error in the XAML file saying: "Input string was not in a correct format" line 1.

I think it's something between `<ContentView>...</ContentView>` because if I remove the content between, then the error goes away.

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Name="this"
             x:Class="App.Controls.IsPublished"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:App.Converters"
             x:DataType="{x:Reference this}">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <converter:IsPublishedToColorConverter x:Key="IsPublishedToColor" IsTrue="{Binding TrueColor}" IsFalse="{Binding FalseColor}" />
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <BoxView CornerRadius="10" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" Color="{Binding Published, Converter={StaticResource IsPublishedToColor}}" />

</ContentView>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class IsPublished : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TrueColorBindable = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TrueColor), typeof(string), typeof(IsPublished), "#08AA04");
    public static readonly BindableProperty FalseColorBindable = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FalseColor), typeof(string), typeof(IsPublished), "#FF3D00");
    public static readonly BindableProperty PublishedBindable = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Published), typeof(bool), typeof(IsPublished), false);


    public string TrueColor { 
        get => (string)GetValue(TrueColorBindable); 
        set => SetValue(TrueColorBindable, value);
    }
    public string FalseColor { 
        get => (string)GetValue(FalseColorBindable);
        set => SetValue(FalseColorBindable, value);
    }

    public bool Published
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(PublishedBindable);
        set => SetValue(PublishedBindable, value);
    }

    public IsPublished()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Converter

```
public class IsPublishedToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object IsTrue { get; set; }
        public object IsFalse { get; set; }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            => (bool)value ? IsTrue : IsFalse;

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            => null;
    }
```

Comment: continue selectively removing lines until you narrow it down, then try selectively removing properties from that line until you find the culprit

Comment: What are `TrueColor`, `FalseColor` and `Published` in your viewmodel?